# XPath: Select element which has specific attribute with special character

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

```
<document>
    <element>
        <attribut a:name="my-name">My Name</attribut>
        <attribut a:parent="parent1">Parent 1</attribut>
    </element>
</document>
```

In this XML document, how to select the node which has the attribut `a:name` ?

Comment: Search here in SO for answers to questions regarding xpath and namespaces.

Comment: I try this, but selected nothing : http://codepad.org/4V9kUNQM

Answer (score 0):

```
$xmlTest = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<document xmlns:a="http://example.org/a">
<element>
    <attribut a:name="my-name">My Name</attribut>
    <attribut a:parent="parent1">Parent 1</attribut>
</element>
</document>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlTest);
echo current($xml->xpath('//element/attribut[@a:name]'));
```